# ValidateSilverlightFrameworkPaths task? What's that?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I have a very strange behavior, when I build my project on my laptop. I get this error:

> The "ValidateSilverlightFrameworkPaths" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is "public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is correctly declared with  in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.

I have no idea whats this all about - i have never setup any task in a project file. I don't know anything about a Task nor declared something in the framework dir. I can build on my other machine. The project is shared via TFS.

Google doesn't give me enough results to work with.
I already deleted everythin on my laptop and pulled it from the TFS again.

Have you some tips, how to solve this error?
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you do not have silverlight installed on your laptop and you try to build a silverlight project.

As the name suggests, the ValidateSilverlightFrameworkPaths taks is part of the build process for Silverlight projects. The mentioned target file is located at

C`:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight\v5.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets`

the assembly containing the task class is named `Microsoft.Silverlight.Build.Tasks.dll` and resides in the same directory.